# ChartDirector Display Single Value

Tags: vb6, chart-director

I have a question
I use BarLayer Add three Dataset 
I can use display all Data

```
setAggregateLabelStyle  
setAggregateLabelFormat
```

but I want display single Data Value Like this
[image]
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to Solve
use `addGroupLabel`

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the label in dynamic layer. Calculate the red bar position and draw the text on it